# How do I prevent styles applied to tags inside the :first-line from being stripped?

Tags: colors, tags, styles, font-size, pseudo-element

Tags falling into a :first-line, lose all their formatting when a rule targeting the :first-line changes anything from it. Not only the targeted properties, but also any other properties applied to the pseudo element are stripped too.

E.g. Changing only the COLOR with :first-line, FONT-SIZE is lost too, from a tag (or pseudo-element) falling inside that first line.

http://jsfiddle.net/wvC5z/3/

```
<p>First line gets properly formatted, but <strong>this text</strong>
loses any other formatting applied</p>
```

Chrome and Safari so far.